# Content Security Policy deactivate

Tags: java, html, jsp, aem, content-security-policy

I develop a new Website. In chrome Browser there are exceptions about 'unsafe-inline'. It's because there are inline javascript and inline style in the HTML. 
I set the X-Content-Security-Policy / Content-Security-Policy to allow Inline-scripts and many more. But there is no effect, for the inline-scripts, other definitions working, like setting url for img-src.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';img-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net https://www.facebook.com http://staticxx.facebook.com;child-src 'self'  https://connect.facebook.net https://www.facebook.com http://staticxx.facebook.com *.facebook.com;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

My Questions are. Is there a way that I can allow it?and why is the unsafe-inline param not working? I know CSP is for better Security, but we have inline-scripts / style, and this is buyed code, so we can't change it.
Why are older pages from me not affected about this Content-Security-Policy and the new one is? Can I turn off the whole CSP stuff?

And I find it interesting that the templates are fine without exceptions from CSP, but when I use the templates on the Webpage ther are exceptions. How can that be? Is this maybe a server config? I use Adobe CQ 6.1.

The Problem with the CSP i just have if im not in the network of the company.

Comment: FYI X-Content-Security-Policy is deprecated and has no practical application since firefox/chrome don't support it anymore and the directives you use aren't supported by old versions of IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.
The meta tag has to be add in server configuration in Virtual Host File, like

#set the content security policy

Header set Content-Security-Policy "default 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"